# Should I design pattern with snap to pixel on or off?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, patterns

I am designing a pattern for my company. It will be used on for print on paper, clothes etc AND as a pattern on my web site and other digital media.

I have not much knowledge about designing. Currently I have created the pattern with the "Print" document type and Snap to pixels off. However, when I export it, it does not look sharp.

Should I instead create the pattern with the "Web" document profile and snap to pixels on?

Or, how do you solve this when I need the pattern for both print and digital media? Do you just ignore it? Or do you make it pixel perfect before exporting it in another document?

Answer (score 1):

It would depend on the pattern.

If it's mostly made of horizontal and vertical lines - then snap to pixel is going to work pretty well.  If it's made of random shapes, with curves and other angles, then it probably won't make any difference - so just switch it off.

Since you want to use the image in a web page, have you thought about exporting it as an SVG and using that in your web page? That might fix it for you.  SVGs are vectors.